# How to use forEachPartition on pyspark dataframe?

Tags: pyspark, rdd

I am trying to use forEachPartition() method using pyspark on a RDD that has 8 partitions. My custom function tries to generate a string output for a given string input. Here is the code

```
from google.cloud import language
from google.cloud.language import enums
from google.cloud.language import types
import pandas as pd
import datetime

def compute_sentiment_score(text):
    client = language.LanguageServiceClient()
    document = types.Document(content=text,type=enums.Document.Type.PLAIN_TEXT, language='en')
    sentiment = client.analyze_sentiment(document=document).document_sentiment
    return str(sentiment.score)

def compute_sentiment_magnitude(text):
    client = language.LanguageServiceClient()
    document = types.Document(content=text,type=enums.Document.Type.PLAIN_TEXT, language='en')
    sentiment = client.analyze_sentiment(document=document).document_sentiment
    return str(sentiment.magnitude)

import os
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="/path-to-file.json"

imdb_reviews = pd.read_csv('imdb_reviews.csv', header=None, names=['input1', 'input2'], encoding= "ISO-8859-1")

imdb_reviews.head()

    input1                                         input2
0   first think another Disney movie, might good, ...   1
1   Put aside Dr. House repeat missed, Desperate H...   0
2   big fan Stephen King's work, film made even gr...   1
3   watched horrid thing TV. Needless say one movi...   0
4   truly enjoyed film. acting terrific plot. Jeff...   1


spark_imdb_reviews = spark.createDataFrame(imdb_reviews) # create spark dataframe


spark_imdb_reviews.printSchema()
root
 |-- input1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- input2: long (nullable = true)
```

And this is my custom function -

```
def compute_sentiment_score(text):
    client = language.LanguageServiceClient()
    document = types.Document(content=text,type=enums.Document.Type.PLAIN_TEXT, language='en')
    sentiment = client.analyze_sentiment(document=document).document_sentiment
    return str(sentiment.score)

def compute_sentiment_magnitude(text):
    client = language.LanguageServiceClient()
    document = types.Document(content=text,type=enums.Document.Type.PLAIN_TEXT, language='en')
    sentiment = client.analyze_sentiment(document=document).document_sentiment
    return str(sentiment.magnitude)
```

Here is how I try to use the forEachPartition() method -

```
create_rdd = spark_imdb_reviews.select("input1").rdd # create RDD
print(create_rdd.getNumPartitions()) # print the partitions
print(create_rdd.take(1)) # display data
new_rdd = create_rdd.foreachPartition(compute_sentiment_score) # compute score
```

Which gives this output and an error -

```
8
[Row(input1="first think another Disney movie, might good, it's kids movie. watch it, can't help enjoy it. ages love movie. first saw movie 10 8 years later still love it! Danny Glover superb could play part better. Christopher Lloyd hilarious perfect part. Tony Danza believable Mel Clark. can't help, enjoy movie! give 10/10!")]

File "<ipython-input-106-e3fd65ce75cc>", line 3, in compute_sentiment_score
TypeError: <itertools.chain object at 0x11ab7f198> has type itertools.chain, but expected one of: bytes, unicode
```

Comment: Are you sure `forEachPartition` is the right way to do what you want to do ? What do you want to achieve ? just apply a function to a rdd ?

Comment: What I want to do is create a client connection only once per RDD. Right now, if i use map or something else, I create as many connection objects as the records. Hence I am looking for something like forEachPartition or mapPartitions. Can you share a working example or suggest a good solution with some code examples?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two similar functions:

- [RDD.forachPartition](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.foreachPartition) and
- [RDD.mapPartitions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.mapPartitions)

Both functions expect another function as parameter (here `compute_sentiment_score`). This function gets the content of a partition passed in form of an iterator. The `text` parameter in the question is actually an iterator that can be used inside of `compute_sentiment_score`.

The difference between `foreachPartition` and `mapPartition` is that `foreachPartition` is a Spark action while `mapPartition` is a transformation. This means the code being called by `foreachPartition` is immediately executed and the RDD remains unchanged while `mapPartition` can be used to create a new RDD. In order to store the calculated sentiment score `mapPartitions` should be used.

```python
def compute_sentiment_score(itr_text):
    #setup the things that are expensive and should be prepared only once per partition
    client = language.LanguageServiceClient()
    
    #run the loop for each row of the partition
    for text in itr_text:
        document = types.Document(content=text.value,type=enums.Document.Type.PLAIN_TEXT, language='en')
        sentiment = client.analyze_sentiment(document=document).document_sentiment
        yield (text.value, sentiment.score)

df_with_score = df.rdd.mapPartitions(compute_sentiment_score)
df_with_score.foreach(print)
```

In this example `client = language.LanguageServiceClient()` is called once per partition. Probably the amount of partitions has to be reduced, for example with [coalesce](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.coalesce).

Comment: thanks for the answer and the explanation. I am facing this issue when I perform the action - `File "<ipython-input-18-654a7c561fb5>", line 22, in compute_sentiment_score
TypeError: Row(input1="first think another Disney movie, might good, it's kids movie. watch it, can't help enjo has type Row, but expected one of: bytes, unicode`

Comment: could you try to replace `text` with `text.value` in the for loop?

Comment: I tried using text.value , it says `ValueError: 'value' is not in list`

Comment: I was even trying out a simple print statement in the for loop like `for text in itr_text: print(text)` but that throws an error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`

Comment: I tried a couple of options here and there like passing text.columnname in the for loop but none of them seem to be work . It would be great if you can help me with a working solution for this. I think we are almost there.

Comment: It should be the name of the column of the original dataset. It was `value` for me (I didnt set one explicitly). Could you please try `input1`?

Comment: when i tried passing text.input1 it complained about the API limits again.

Comment: that's good news. Then the code of `compute_sentiment_score` is now working. You could now try to reduce the number of partitions to reduce the load on the API. Could you try `create_rdd = spark_imdb_reviews.select("input1").coalesce(1).rdd`?

Comment: I tried `coalesce` , it now threw an error saying - `File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1062, in _infer_schema
    raise TypeError("Can not infer schema for type: %s" % type(row))
TypeError: Can not infer schema for type: <class 'google.cloud.language_v1.types.Sentiment'>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221283/discussion-between-werner-and-regressor).

Comment: thank you for the answer. I am able to avoid the API limit errors and also able to generate the sentiment scores for each record in my dataframe